# Getting the size of a S3 image from Stream using C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, stream

I've uploaded an image to Amazon Web Service S3. I am reading the image from S3 using `client.GetObject`.

I am converting the image to a series of bytes. In order to do so, I am creating a buffer (`byte[]`) to hold the data when I convert the stream to bytes using `Stream.read`.

In order to do so, I need to allocate the right amount of bytes for the buffer array.

My question is: How can I get the size of the image after it has been read to `S3Response object`.I know I can run responseObject.ResponseStream to get the stream, but how do I get the size of the stream?

Developing with AWS SDK .NET C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better and optimized solution for transferring the files to and from s3 is TransferUtility in AWS Sdk. As:

```
using (var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(client))
{
    var request = new TransferUtilityDownloadRequest();
    request.BucketName = BucketName;
    request.FilePath = desination;
    request.Key = key;
    fileTransferUtility.Download(request);
}
```

Comment: How can I access the response, downlaod returns void

Comment: It will copy the file from s3 to desination. You can check this by new FileInfo(desination).Exists;

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ResponseStream.Length` property which gives the length of the object in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

ResponseStream.Length throws an exception because it's a network stream ("does not support seeking").

Before requesting the stream itself, get its info with a directory listing:

```
var request = new ListObjectsV2Request
{
    BucketName = bucketName,
    Prefix = $"{folderName}/{fileName}"
};
var response = Client.ListObjectsV2(request);
var fileSize = response.S3Objects.Any() ? response.S3Objects.First().Size : 0;
```